# asp.net roles provider sample code

Tags: asp.net

i want to implement asp.net role provider to assign users over my LAN to roles and have my asp.net intranet app implement security based on roles.

i dont want to use VS to manage this witht he built in tools but rather hand this off to users to manage themselves. i want an admin folder with a few pages for admin roles to be able to create/edit roles and manage users in roles...

i am not able to find sample code... can anyone provide me a link to some sample i can use to admin roles and users?

thanks

Comment: Are you using windows authentication or forms? I am guessing windows since you are talking about an intranet, but I wan't to make sure.

Comment: yes i am using windows authentication. well not realy, i am just logging user activity based on windows authentication. now i want to lock down certain parts of the app based on roles.

Comment: my app is in C# so a c# sample would be best !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of simple examples of role provider implementation sample on web waiting to be "Googled"

well but if you need to create a admin panel - for management of roles (and obviously for membership for user management if using one) you should get your hands dirty on this (suggestion).

[Role Management Basics - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx)

Show how to CHOOSE / CONFIGURE / MANAGE (storedprocedure / Role provider ASP.net API )

Other than that you can use the objectbrowser (View > ObjectBrowser) windows of VISUAL STUDIO to dive into the API which gives useful information of methods / properties in API (Under System > Web > Security > ....) which could be helpful.

Hope it helps

Regards, J'Sinh.

Comment: thanks but there is nothing interesting in making more boilerplate code and i am on a time crunch and would like somethign pre-made already.